# Debian Stretch and Realtek r8152 chipset carrier off/on error

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, hardware-failure

I've bought some USB-Ethernet adapter based on Realtek r8152 chipset. And it works perfectly under my Debian "Stretch", but it works like this only if you plug it after OS gets loaded. If OS starts with this adapter attached - internet connection continuously hangs, like every 5 seconds, it automatically connects, and disconnects. As I said, if you just unplug and then plug it again to the same USB port - it starts working perfectly (Completely stable and on full speed).
What causes this problem?

Kernel:

```
Linux debian1 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg:

```
[ 12.228505] r8152: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 12.229483] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[ 12.318856] usb 3-2.4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 12.485312] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 eth0: v2.09.00 (2017/08/21)
[ 12.485315] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 eth0: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[ 12.489952] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[ 13.054437] Adding 5858300k swap on /dev/sda5. Priority:-1 extents:1 across:5858300k FS
[ 13.107585] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 13.280075] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[ 13.444964] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: renamed from eth0
[ 25.323920] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c68006a: link is not ready
[ 25.332487] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c68006a: link is not ready
[ 25.363705] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 25.363722] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx00e04c68006a: link becomes ready
[ 86.498696] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 100.536995] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 102.683454] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 119.184080] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 125.427705] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 139.526354] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 141.132447] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 157.597714] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 250.171318] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 264.170763] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 267.507029] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 281.410521] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 285.764174] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 299.674468] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 303.904214] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 317.877783] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 319.962530] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 336.371308] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
[ 338.261249] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier off
[ 354.642913] r8152 3-2.4:1.0 enx00e04c68006a: carrier on
```

These carrier on/off events are connection hang events.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in Link negotiation settings. I just changed them in GUI from default "Ignore" value to "Manual" and now everything is stable.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and I've been experiencing exactly the same issue in Debian 11 (bullseye) with kernel v. 5.10 on x86_64 CPU architecture:

```
[   48.055739] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd8d0900d73ec: carrier off
[   51.797465] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd8d0900d73ec: carrier on
[   73.048046] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd8d0900d73ec: carrier off
[   76.757587] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd8d0900d73ec: carrier on
[   98.071303] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd8d0900d73ec: carrier off
[  101.717368] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd8d0900d73ec: carrier on
[  101.803242] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd8d0900d73ec: carrier off
```

In my case changing the `Link Negotiation` (*Negocjacja łącza*) option in the KDE's network settings from default `Automatic` (*Samoczynnie*) to `Skip` (*Pomiń*) solved the problem!

[image]